# Oracle Case Statement and efficency

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a piece of my Oracle Query i need to optimize a little

```
select
case 
    when SUM(dnl.quantity) = line.quantity then 1 
    when SUM(dnl.quantity) < line.quantity then 0 
    when SUM(dnl.quantity) > line.quantity then 2 
end
from mytable dnl
```

line.quantity comes out from other part o query, for this example is not needed i think. I would like to calculate only once SUM(dnl.quantity) instead ad every iteraciotn, somethink like

```
select
case SUM(dnl.quantity)
    when line.quantity then 1 
    when < line.quantity then 0 
    when > line.quantity then 2 
end
from mytable dnl
```

But obviously this give error at the second and 3rd WHEN

Comment: To help you with the performance of a query we would need to see the entire query. The execution plan (and the optimization engine) considers the query as a whole, not just parts of it.

Comment: I knwo, but i can't reveal more than this due to Company Policies. I think the point is to avoid only to repeta the sum calculation.

Comment: The sum will be computed only once and used in all three places. If you are really concerned about that (if you don't believe it), compute the sum in a subquery and use the `case` expression in a higher-level query.

Comment: Why do you think you "need to optimize a little" on that section? Why do you think that section is causing a speed problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are over-optimizing.  The Oracle compiler can decide how many times it wants to evaluate `sum(dnl.quantity)`.  However, the *data movement* is usually much more expensive than the calculation of aggregations on a single column.

That said if you are really concerned about this, you can use `sign()`:

```
(case sign(sum(dnl.quantity) - line_quantity)
     when 0 then 1 
     when -1 then 0 
     when 1 then 2 
 end)
```

Or to be more inscrutible:

```
sign(sum(dnl.quantity) - line_quantity) + 1
```

Comment: To be more explicit for OP, just because `SUM(dnl.quantity)` appears in the code three times doesn't mean that Oracle does the same work three times.

Comment: Shouldn't `when 0 = line.quantity then 1` be `when 0 then 1`?